# How to test webcam functionality in TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

So basically I want to write an E2E test which involves user's webcam, but I have no idea how to work around giving permission to use webcam or mock it. It's a distant study software for schools and one of main functionalities is that students/teachers can upload files and record videos for school projects and then download the generated .webm file. Currently I can't get the browser to give TestCafe permissions to use webcam.

I've tried giving Chrome these parameters `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-fake-device-for-media-stream`

Here's some of my sample code, after 'start video recording' it should grant permission:

```
    .click(Selector('.assignment-title').withText('Testcafe task'))
    .click(Selector('.uppy-DashboardTab-name').withText('Use camera'))
    .click(Selector('button[title="Start video recording"]'))
```

And to my understanding it should somehow be possible with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})`, but how to migrate this into my code or how does it all come together?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [testcafe-examples](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples) repository that uses this functionality: [Mock Camera/Microphone Access](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/detached-examples/mock-camera-microphone-access).
If the example doesn't help you, please update your question with more details (a minimal project or a public URL with your test code would be of help).

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, I didn't know about that page before. I managed to get it to work perfectly and get better understanding overall.